# Inconsistency when trying to sort one vector based on another vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

In the following C++ code, I am trying to use sort function to sort one vector based on another one. For example, if `v1 = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `v2 = (-1.1, 1.5, 0.2, 4, 3)`, then after calling my function `relative_sort (v1,v2)` we should have `v1 = (1, 3, 2, 5, 4)`. I don't understand why the code does not work properly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
void print_vector (vector<double> & v)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < v.size() ; i++)
        cout << v[i] << ' ' ;
}
void relative_sort (vector<double> & v1 , vector<double> & v2) // sort v1 based on v2
{

    int n = v1.size();
    if ( n != v2.size())
        cout << endl << "Error: The length of v1 is not the same as v2" << endl ;
    else if (n<1)
        cout << endl<< "Error: Empty Vectors" << endl ;
    else
        {
            std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), [&v2](int a, int b) { return v2[a] < v2[b]; } );
        }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    vector <double> v2 ;
    vector <double> v1 ;
    vector <double> v0 ;
    double a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    v0.assign(a,a+5);
    double b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    v1.assign(b,b+5);
    double c[] = {-1.1 , 1.5 , 0.2 , 4, 3};
    v2.assign(c,c+5);

    cout << endl << "V0: " ;
    print_vector(v0) ;
    cout << endl << "V1: " ;
    print_vector(v1) ;
    cout << endl << "V2: " ;
    print_vector(v2) ;
    cout << endl ;

    relative_sort (v0 , v2);

    cout << endl << "V0: " ;
    print_vector(v0) ;

    relative_sort (v1 , v2);

    cout << endl << "V1: " ;
    print_vector(v1) ;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is

```
V0: 0 1 2 3 4 
V1: 1 2 3 4 5 
V2: -1.1 1.5 0.2 4 3 

V0: 0 2 1 4 3 
V1: 5 2 1 4 3
```

The output for `v0` is correct while it is not for `v1`. It seems that it works only for `v0` and not for any other vector!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior since not all values from `v1` are valid indices for `v2`. In particular, `5` is an invalid index for `v2`.

Here's a way accomplish what you want to:

1. Create a `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>` created from `v1` and `v2`.
2. Sort new object using the second of the pair.
3. Pull out the values from the sorted vector and assign them to `v1`.

Here's an updated version of the function.

```
void relative_sort (vector<double> & v1 , vector<double> & v2) // sort v1 based on v2
{
   size_t n = v1.size();
   if ( n != v2.size())
      cout << endl << "Error: The length of v1 is not the same as v2" << endl ;
   else if (n<1)
      cout << endl<< "Error: Empty Vectors" << endl ;
   else
   {
      std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> v3(n);
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
      {
         v3[i] = {v1[i], v2[i]}
      }

      std::sort(v3.begin(), v3.end(), [](std::pair<double, double> a,
                                         std::pair<double, double> b)
                                      { return a.second < b.second; } );

      for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
      {
         v1[i] = v3[i].first;
      }
   }
}
```

You can probably use [`boost::zip_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) to simplify that task but I have not used it myself.

---

Update, in response to OP's comment.

If you change `v1` to be of type `std::vector<size_t>` instead of `std::vector<double>` and make sure that it contains `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, then you may use:

```
std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(),
         [&v2](size_t a, size_t b) { return v2[a] < v2[b]; } );
```

to sort the indices without a problem.

You can also update your function so that `v1` is resized to match the size of `v2` and make sure to set the indices correctly before calling `sort`.

```
// Get sorted indices in v1 based on values in v2
void relative_sort (vector<size_t> & v1 , vector<double> & v2)
{
   size_t n = v2.size();
   if (n<1)
      cout << endl<< "Error: Empty Vectors" << endl ;
   else
   {
      v1.resize(n);
      for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i )
      {
         v1[i] = i;
      }

      std::sort(v1.begin(), v2.end(),
                [&v2](size_t a, size_t b) { return v2[a] < v2[b]; } );    
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks R. I am trying to write my code as efficiently as possible. I think because you are using loops to accomplish the job, it increases the complexity somehow by `O(n)`. I did not know that contents of `v1` are used as indices for `v2`. What if in the original code, I use `v1 = 0 1 2 3 4` as the vector of 'indices', sort the index vector, and then use it wherever I want to call the original vector `v2`?

Comment: @Opt, yes, you can do that. Make sure `v1` is of type `std::vector<size_t>`, not `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: @R Sahu, Excellent! Can I use `int` instead of `size_t`?

Comment: @Opt, yes you can.

Comment: An alternative would be to create an array of indexes, sort the array of indexes according to v2, then sort v1 and v2 according to the sorted indexes. This avoids having to alter the arrays into an array or vector of pairs and is more generic (easily modified to handle >2 arrays). Note it's possible to reorder arrays in place according to an array of sorted indexes.